# How do I pass a params parameter into an rspec controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, parameters

I have the following rspec test:

```
def valid_attributes
  { "product_id" => "1" }
end

describe "POST create" do
  describe "with valid params" do
    it "creates a new LineItem" do
      expect {
        post :create, {:line_item => valid_attributes}, valid_session #my valid_session is blank
      }.to change(LineItem, :count).by(1)
    end
```

Which fails with this error:

```
1) LineItemsController POST create with valid params redirects to the created line_item
   Failure/Error: post :create, {:line_item => valid_attributes}, valid_session
   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
     Couldn't find Product without an ID
     # ./app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:44:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/line_items_controller_spec.rb:87:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is my controller's create action:

```
def create
  @cart = current_cart
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product => product)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @line_item.cart, status: :created, location: @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, my action expects a product_id from the request's `params` object.  **How should I work this product_id into my rspec test?**

I've tried placing this `before` statement:

```
before(:each) do
    ApplicationController.any_instance.stub(:product).and_return(@product = mock('product'))
  end
```

. . . but it changes nothing.  I am missing some rspec concept here somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving my issue by using a fixture instead of attempting to mock the solution as suggested in another answer.

The reason for this is that the controller does the query to get information from the database: `product = Product.find(params[:product_id])` and I found a fixture-based solution was quicker to resolve my problem than one using a mock and I could not figure out how to stub the query quickly (the fixtures also help with another test on the controller so it eventually helped anyway.

For reference:

I referenced my fixture with this line toward the top of the test: `fixtures :products`

I changed my test to:

```
describe "POST create" do
  describe "with valid params" do
    it "creates a new LineItem" do
      expect {
          post :create, :product_id => products(:one).id
       }.to change(LineItem, :count).by(1)
    end
```

And here is my fixture file, products.yml:

```
one:
    name: FirstProduct
    price: 1.23

two:
    name: SecondProduct
    price: 4.56
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
describe "POST create" do
   describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new LineItem" do
         expect {
            post :create, :product_id => 1
         }.to change(LineItem, :count).by(1)
      end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I make the change, my error changes to: `Couldn't find Product with id=1` This would be because there's no fixture representing the product -- how should I resolve this?  I feel it would be better to stub out the object, but would creating a fixture be a more suitable solution?

Comment: I use mock_model from RSpec, check this: http://fr.ivolo.us/posts/rspec-tutorial-part-4-mocking

Comment: I am not sure where I am actually supposed to stub the Product so that it shows up in the context of the params object.  I have tried right before the `expect { . . . }` block, and within the `before` block - but I am not sure if it is my syntax that is the issue or if I have the context wrong.  (I am repeatedly left with the error: `Couldn't find Product with id=1` )

Comment: You can use it any place before expect. You can try just mock, not stub.